# Oracle Self Join to retrieve recursive data

Tags: oracle, join, inner-join, self-join

I have the following schema and data

```
segmentid  paramid  paramvalue
103 1   4418

101 1   4834

102 1   5587

104 1   7413

105 1   9965

106 1   7421

107 1   7782

103 2   1990|2000

102 2   2005|2010

105 2   1985|1990

104 2   1981

101 3   F

103 3   M

101 4   M

103 4   S

102 5   SUKKHUR

105 5   LAHORE

106 5   HYDRABAD

107 5   KHAIRPUR

101 5   ISLAMABAD
```

Now i will have inputs of different param values like Karachi M and date of birth range. I want to retrieve only that segment id whose all parameters are returned to be true.
If any parameter is failed the segment should fail.
Below is my idea but its returning if any paramvalue is true as ive used `or` but when i `and` the data is not retrieved.

```
select tpv.* from tblsegment ts , tblsegmentparameter tsp , tblsegmentparamvalue tpv
where ts.segmentid = tpv.segmentid and tsp.parameterid = tpv.paramid
and 
(
(lower(tsp.paramname) like 'city' and tpv.paramvalue = 'KARACHI' and tsp.parameterid = tpv.paramid) 
or
(lower(tsp.paramname) like 'gender' and tpv.paramvalue = 'M') 
or
(lower(tsp.paramname) like 'maritalstatus' and tpv.paramvalue = 'S') 
or
(lower(tsp.paramname) like 'product' and tpv.paramvalue = (select distinct ta.productid  from tblcustchannelacct ta ,tblcustomer tc, tblaccount tta 
where ta.relationship_id = '5327016301000015=5311' and ta.channel_id = '0001' and ta.account_id = tta.account_id and ta.customer_id = tc.customerid )
)
or
(lower(tsp.paramname) like 'dob' and 
  (
   (
    to_char( '1985') between
    to_char( REGEXP_SUBSTR ( tpv.paramvalue, '^[^|]*')) 
    and   

    to_char(REGEXP_SUBSTR( tpv.paramvalue, '*[^|]*$'))   
   ) or
   (
   to_char( '1986') = tpv.paramvalue
   )
  )
)
)
order by tsp.sortorder;
```

Comment: Are you stuck with this particular data model? Because (IMHO) it's a pretty rubbish design - as you're now finding out when you try to query anything.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3723/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblsegmentparamvalue ( segmentid,  paramid,  paramvalue ) AS
          SELECT 103, 1,   '4418' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 101, 1,   '4834' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 102, 1,   '5587' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 104, 1,   '7413' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 105, 1,   '9965' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 106, 1,   '7421' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 107, 1,   '7782' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 103, 2,   '1990|2000' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 102, 2,   '2005|2010' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 105, 2,   '1985|1990' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 104, 2,   '1981' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 101, 3,   'F' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 103, 3,   'M' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 101, 4,   'M' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 103, 4,   'S' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 102, 5,   'SUKKHUR' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 105, 5,   'LAHORE' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 106, 5,   'HYDRABAD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 107, 5,   'KHAIRPUR' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 101, 5,   'ISLAMABAD' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH segments AS (
  SELECT segmentid
  FROM   tblsegmentparamvalue
  GROUP BY segmentid
  HAVING (   COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 1 THEN 1 END ) = 0
         OR  COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 1 AND paramvalue = '4834'      THEN 1 END ) > 0 )
  AND    (   COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 2 THEN 1 END ) = 0
         OR  COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 2 AND '1985' BETWEEN SUBSTR( paramvalue, 1, 4 ) AND SUBSTR( paramvalue, -4 ) THEN 1 END ) > 0 )
  AND    (   COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 3 THEN 1 END ) = 0
         OR  COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 3 AND paramvalue = 'F'         THEN 1 END ) > 0 )
  AND    (   COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 4 THEN 1 END ) = 0
         OR  COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 4 AND paramvalue = 'M'         THEN 1 END ) > 0 )
  AND    (   COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 5 THEN 1 END ) = 0
         OR  COUNT( CASE WHEN paramid = 5 AND paramvalue = 'ISLAMABAD' THEN 1 END ) > 0 )
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   tblsegmentparamvalue t
       INNER JOIN
       segments s
       ON ( t.segmentid = s.segmentid )
ORDER BY
       t.segmentid,
       paramid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3723/8/0)**:

```
| SEGMENTID | PARAMID | PARAMVALUE |
|-----------|---------|------------|
|       101 |       1 |       4834 |
|       101 |       3 |          F |
|       101 |       4 |          M |
|       101 |       5 |  ISLAMABAD |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to get results for three paramters:

```
select segmentid, paramid, paramvalue 
  from (
    select tpv.*, count(distinct paramid) over (partition by tpv.segmentid) cnt
      from tblsegmentparamvalue tpv 
        join tblsegment ts on ts.segmentid = tpv.segmentid
        join tblsegmentparameter tsp on tsp.parameterid = tpv.paramid
      where (lower(tsp.paramname) like 'city' and tpv.paramvalue = 'KARACHI')
         or (lower(tsp.paramname) like 'gender' and tpv.paramvalue = 'M')
         or (lower(tsp.paramname) like 'martialstatus' and tpv.paramvalue = 'S') )
  where cnt = 3
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fcc18/1)</sup>

Add rest of parameters (dob, product) as you did it in your query and change last line to `where cnt=5` to get full results.